# Problema com LOCK de arquivo gravado pelo PDFWriter

Tags: itextsharp

Estou gravando um arquivo no servidor (ASP.NET) que é um PDF e para isso estou usando o Itextsharp. Tudo está funcionando corretamente o meu problema é que quando eu tento gerar o segundo PDF ele me da mensagem de erro falando que o arquiv está em uso por outro processo.

Já usei todos os recursos que eu conheço para liberar o arquivo mas sem resultado.

Alguem tem alguma sugestão...???

Segue o trecho do código..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a ajuda.
Eduardo

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código devidamente formatado.

Comment: `doc.Close()` é suficiente para fechar o ficheiro. De certeza que não é o `Mandar_Email()` ou outra coisa que não está a fazer o lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela dica... você acertou o problema.
Era a rotina de Mandar_Email que anexava o arquivo para envia-lo e ele acabava fica aberto por ela. Coloquei um mail.Attachments.Dispose() e resolveu o problema.

Obrigado.
Abraços.